# How to close a socket that is listening but has not accepted connections yet

Tags: python, sockets, user-interface

I have a socket that listens to incoming connections and I'm able to close the connection using a button once it has been established and data is moving, but would it be possible for me to use a button to stop the socket even before a connection is established and the while loop begins?

Here is the code for the socket:

```
def serverstart(self):
          self.buttonswitch("1")
          host = self.intip
          port = 5000
          s= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6)
          s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
          s.bind((host, port))

          s.listen(1)
          c, addr = s.accept()
          print "Connection from: " + str(addr)
          self.serverstatus = "1"
          status = self.serverstatus
          while status == "1":
                data = c.recv(1500)
                print len(data)
                if not data:
                        break
                data = str(data).upper()
                c.send(data)
                status = self.serverstatus
          c.close()
          s.close()
          print "Closing socket"
          self.buttonswitch("0")
```

I use the buttonswitch function to enable and disable the stop and start buttons in tandem with the state of the server

EDIT: I got rid of the self.serverstatus variable and added this instead (create a connection to the socket just to shut it down):

```
def serverstop(self, status):
          s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6)
          self.s.close()
          try:
                self.c.close()
          except:
                s.connect((self.host,self.port))
                s.close()
          self.buttonswitch("0")
```

The only drawback with this is that when I shut down a connection it raises an error about a broken pipe. This doesn't affect the functionality though.

If you have any ideas for this to be more correct I'd be happy to learn, thank you.

EDIT2: I'll post all the code involved for the reference:

```
from Tkinter import *
import socket, threading, time
import netifaces as ni

class Application(Frame):


        def __init__(self, master):
          """ Initialize the Frame"""
          Frame.__init__(self,master)
          self.grid()
          self.create_widgets()

        def create_widgets(self):
          self.label1 = Label(text = "Target IPv6 address")
          self.label1.grid(row=1, column=0)

          self.entry1 = Entry(bd = 5)
          self.entry1.grid(row=1, column = 1, columnspan = 2)

          self.button1 = Button(text = "Start", command = lambda: self.threadcontrol("2"))
          self.button1.grid(row=1, column = 3)

          self.button2 = Button(text = "Start", command = lambda: self.threadcontrol("1"), state = DISABLED)
          self.button2.grid(row=2, column=3)

          self.button3 = Button(text = "Stop", command = lambda: self.serverstop("0"), state = DISABLED)
          self.button3.grid(row=2, column=4)

          self.button4 = Button(text = "Stop", command = lambda: self.clientstop("0"), state = DISABLED)
          self.button4.grid(row=1, column=4)

          self.label2 = Label(text = "Choose interface to listen")
          self.label2.grid(row=2, column=0)

          self.interfaces = Menubutton(text="------", relief=RAISED)
          self.interfaces.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="w")
          self.interfaces.menu = Menu(self.interfaces, tearoff=0)
          self.interfaces["menu"] = self.interfaces.menu
          self.menubox()

          self.label3 = Label(text = "")
          self.label3.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="w")

        def menubox(self):
          self.interfaces.menu.add_command(label="------", command = lambda interface="------": self.callback(interface))
          for interface in ni.interfaces():
                if interface.startswith('eth'):
                  self.interfaces.menu.add_command(label=interface, command = lambda interface=interface: self.callback(interface))
                else:
                  pass

        def callback(self, interface):
          if interface.startswith('eth'):
                self.intip = ni.ifaddresses(interface)[ni.AF_INET6][0]['addr']
                self.interfaces["text"] = interface
                if self.intip.startswith('fe80'):
                  self.label3["text"] = "No IPv6 address found"
                  self.button2["state"] = DISABLED
                else:
                  self.label3["text"] = self.intip
                  self.button2["state"] = 'normal'
          else:
                self.interfaces["text"] = "------"
                self.label3["text"] = ""
                self.button2["state"] = DISABLED

        def buttonswitch(self, flip):
          if flip == "1":
                # Disables server start button and enables server stop button.
                self.button2["state"] = DISABLED
                self.button3["state"] = "normal"
          elif flip == "0":
                # Disables server stop button and enables server start button
                self.button3["state"] = DISABLED
                self.button2["state"] = 'normal'
          elif flip == "2":
                # Enables client stop button
                self.button4["state"] = 'normal'
          elif flip == "3":
                # Disables client stop button
                self.button4["state"] = DISABLED

        def threadcontrol(self, threadtype):
          if threadtype == "1":
                self.thread1 = threading.Thread(target = self.serverstart)
                self.thread1.start()
          elif threadtype == "2":
                self.thread2 = threading.Thread(target = self.clientstart)
                self.thread2.start()
          else:
                pass

        def clientstop(self, status):
          self.clientstatus = "1"
          if status =="0":
                self.clientstatus = status

        def serverstop(self, status):
          self.s.close()

        def serverstart(self):
          self.buttonswitch("1")
          self.host = self.intip
          self.port = 5000
          self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6)
          self.s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
          self.s.bind((self.host, self.port))

          self.s.listen(1)
          self.c, addr = self.s.accept()
          print "Connection from: " + str(addr)
          while True:
                data = self.c.recv(1500)
                print len(data)
                if not data:
                        break
                data = str(data).upper()
                self.c.send(data)
          self.c.close()
          self.s.close()
          print "Closing socket"
          self.buttonswitch("0")

        def clientstart(self):
          targetip = self.entry1.get()
          host = targetip
          port = 5000

          s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6)
          s.connect((host,port))

          self.buttonswitch("2")
          openfile = open('paskadata')
          message = openfile.read()
          self.clientstatus = "1"
          status = self.clientstatus
          n = 1
          while status == "1":
                s.send(message)
                data = s.recv(1500)
                status = self.clientstatus
                print n
                n = n + 1
                time.sleep(50.0 / 1000)
          s.close()
          self.buttonswitch("3")

root = Tk()

root.title("IPv6 traffic generator")
root.geometry("450x200")

app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't understand how you expect this to work. Even if the GUI is running in a different thread from the server, so it can modify `self.serverstatus` while the server is busy processing messages, that still isn't going to have any effect if you're blocked on `recv` or `send`.

Comment: Anyway, if you just make `s` and `c` member variables, you can always call `self.s.close()` and `self.c.close()` (first check that they exist, if that's appropriate), which I'm pretty sure is guaranteed to interrupt any blocking `accept`, `recv`, `send` on that socket and cause it to raise either `EBADFD`, `ECONNRESET`, or `EINTR`.

Comment: I tried to change the variables to self.s and self.c respectively, but while I was able to close the connection after it had started by using self.c.close(), using self.s.close() didn't stop the socket from listening for connections.

Comment: In your edited version, you're still using a local variable `s`, not `self.s`. Also, I just explained to you that `self.c.close()` is going to make a blocked `recv` raise an `ECONNRESET` or similar error, so I'm not sure why you're surprised that it raises an error.

Comment: More importantly, you still have to explain to us how you're running your GUI and your server in parallel. Are you using a separate thread for each one? Or something like `gevent`? Or what? Because you have to be doing _something_.

Comment: Actually, from your description, "create a connection to the socket just to close it", I think that's where your problem is. Creating a client socket that talks to your server socket doesn't give you a handle on the server socket; if it did, any remote client could do whatever he wanted to any server.

Comment: I'm using a separate thread for the server to function with my GUI. It would indeed be better if self.s.close() worked.

Comment: What's the point of `if self.c.close():` with two calls to `self.s.close()` underneath it? `socket.close` always returns `None`, so you're never going to call `self.s.close()`. Plus, even without that spurious `if`, in the case where you haven't created `self.c` yet at all, because no client has connected, this is going to raise an exception on `self.c.close()`, so you'll never get to `self.s.close()`. And if you never call it, it obviously won't work.

Comment: Also, the haphazard collection of 2, 6, 8, or 10 spaces for each indentation level makes me think there's a good chance you're mixing tabs and spaces at least once, and therefore something you think is inside an `if` isn't or vice-versa…

Comment: At first i did have only self.s.close() and nothing else in function serverstop but it still accepted connections. I have the self.c.close() there because there are also instances when a client is connected and the server needs to be shut down.

EDIT: the second self.s.close() was a a mistake

Comment: Given that your current code is nonsensical (again, the `if self.c.close():` means that anything in that `if` block will never run), I'm not going to assume that your previous code was correct and your platform's sockets library is broken.

Comment: I edited my code to look just like it did at first. I assume it should close the socket when I call the function serverstop, but I can still connect to the socket after calling it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `accept` is a blocking call by default. You won't actually return from `accept` unless there is already a pending connection present on the queue.

You could use an asynchronous library like [`gevent`](http://www.gevent.org/) and spin up a separate greenlet in which you process the user interface events.

Alternatively, you could set the socket to be non-blocking directly by using the [`setblocking`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setblocking) method on the socket. This will require you to "retry" any potentially blocking socket calls using a polling type method.

Another similar approach would be to use the [`settimeout`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout) method which will cause the blocking operations to timeout if any of them take too long. You could set your timeout to something reasonable like 50 milliseconds that a human wouldn't be bothered by and periodically handle UI events. Again, you'll need to retry the blocking socket calls when the timeouts occur.

Personally, I prefer the greenlet approach because it is much simpler.

Comment: But so is `recv` (and `send`), so if there's no data to receive, his button isn't going to work there either.

Comment: True, but my answer involves making all of the socket operations non-blocking one way or another.

Comment: It didn't at the time I wrote that. But my point is that we kind of need to know how/why his button already works before we can explain whether it's possible to make it also work on `accept` or whether he has to completely change his design.

Comment: My button changes the self.serverstatus state to 0, which is enough to stop the while loop. I'm making a packet generator that works for IPv6 so once the connection starts the loop iterates thousands of times in a second. The only problem is that I need some other way to close the socket before a client connects to it.

Comment: For your last edit, using `settimeout` and retrying like that is generally more complicated and convoluted than just using `select` (or, if you're on 3.4+, the `selectors` module, which is a bit simpler).